# Chromecast and allow home media streaming

Tags: video, stream, chromecast

Would Chrome case will allow streaming Home video and pictures using a laptop or home server ? 
or would it allow user to use home media theater software like Media Browser 3 or plex ?

Answer (score 0):

Plex has support for Chromecast, if that is what you were asking.